# Roku SG: Can be change default behaviour and direction of ScrollingLabel node?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working for Roku Scene Graph application. I used "**ScrollingLabel**" node, it is scrolling label text right to left until the end of the string is visible, then transition back to the partial string with the end then it transitions to the full string.
**Can be change default behavior and direction of scrolling?** I want to scroll text right to left like marquee for example-[direction of scrolling text...](http://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/)

Answer (score 0):

It is the standard behaviour, Why would you want a different one and what is it??
You will have to create a new Node, using the Group node with Label and define Animation node as well. That will be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the scroll direction. Nor can you control how long it takes before resetting the position of the text. Very frustrating, I know. :)

Your best bet is to create a custom component and write it yourself. Use a Label node, an Animation node, and probably make use of the clippingRect field as well.